# Library choice according to $LD_LIBRARY_PATH and architecture

Tags: linux, architecture, ldd

For the demonstration I made 2 folders with 2 versions of libgcc_s.so.1
And I looked for library choice according to ldd:

```
> file {A,B}/libgcc_s.so.1
A/libgcc_s.so.1: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), stripped
B/libgcc_s.so.1: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), stripped

> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=A:B ldd MyProgram | grep libgcc_s.so.1
libgcc_s.so.1 => B/libgcc_s.so.1
```

Why MyProgram does not use A/libgcc_s.so.1 ?
I understand that is a matter of architecture but how A/libgcc_s.so.1 is considered invalid and how can I test it manually ?

Answer (score 0):

The [ELF header's](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/14wi-cs140/pintos/specs/sysv-abi-update.html/ch4.eheader.html) third field is "machine" which has the value 62 for amd64 (x86_64) and 3 for i386 (80386).  The loader of course will inspect this field to determine whether it can use a given library, and if not it will continue to the next path in its search list.

Comment: Ok,but how can I determine if a library is compliant with the current architecture ?
I can get the 18-19th bytes of the ELF, but I don't know how determine if this code is compliant with my actual architecture.
Doing [[ $(readelf -h | grep $(Machine:)) == \*$(uname -i)\* ]] it is safe ?

Comment: What's the actual goal you're trying to accomplish at a higher level?

Comment: I have shared folders across different platforms containing different libraries for different architectures.
My actual LD_LIBRARY_PATH include all of them. I want to reduce it with only useful folder according to the architecture without using any naming convention.

Comment: Then I think you should make folders named the same as the output of `uname -m` (e.g. x86_64).

Comment: **without using any naming convention**

Comment: Well then sure, scan the output of readelf or `file(1)` or whatever and do string matching.  Seems like a worse idea than having a naming convention but that's just my opinion.

Comment: I agree with John: Then what is the right way to determine if a dynamic library is compliant with the current platform ?

Comment: The way everyone else does it is using a naming convention.  But you already ruled that out for some reason.